# How to unmap a insert-key on vim?

Tags: vim, vim-macros

On `vim`, *command-mode* keys can be mapped through the `ex` command `:map <key> <macro>` and *insert-mode* keys can be mapped through `:map! <key> <macro>`. After mapped, the commands to remove the mapping from the *command-mode* keys and *insert-mode* keys are `unmap <key>` and `unmap! <key>` respectively.

This works well with *command-mode* keys, but with *insert-mode* keys the key expansion also works on the `ex` command line prompt: trying to type the key end up in the macro expansion taking place resulting in bad argument to the `unmap!` command (`E474: Invalid Argument`) or maybe the command might try to unmap some different key from the one intended (`E31: No such mapping`).

How can someone correctly remove a *insert-mode* mapped key on `vim`?

Comment: Forget `map` and `:map!` that we used to use on plain vi decades ago. Prefer the precise mapping commands `imap`, `smap`, `xmap`, `cmap` and `nmap`. Or even better, the nore versions. With these you wouldn't have been bothered with the unwanted side effects you've experimented.

Comment: That explains why I was having a hard time finding an answer on this issue! The book I'm reading on `vim` will probably still get to those, it starts on `vi` and then gets to `vim` (and maybe a little bit of other clones). Do they differ much from the regular `vi` mapping? I'm guessing `imap` and `cmap` stand for *insert-mode* mapping and *command-mode* mapping?

Comment: They differ in the sense that's easy to encounter undesired side effects, and in the sense that we definitively don't want them to do the same thing, which means that a simple mapping won't do. Regarding your guesses, they are correct. Just use `:help :imap` & al to see exactly what they are doing. BTW, `:help :help` is vim `man man`.

Comment: `:cmap` is "command-line mode mapping", `:imap` is "insert mode mapping", and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While mapping a key, `CTRL+V` can be used to escape some special characters like `ENTER`, `ESC` or some particular control keys.

The same applies when using mapped insert-mode keys: they can be escaped when preceded by `CTRL+V` both while editing the text and while writing commands to the `ex` command-line prompt.

If for example, the `+` insert-key is mapped to some macro and the user wants to unmap it, the key must be escaped while writing the `ex` command to avoid the macro expansion:

`:unmap!` + `CTRL+V` (shows a `^`) + `<key>`

The same can be done if a regular `+` is needed in the text while editing it in *insert-mode*.